# Angularjs ng-model not filling from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

JSON data I am getting from my angular service is not populating `ng-model`. I try to put the data in alert box like `alert(data.Usr_UserId)` but it showing `undefined` in alertbox. Below is my code.

1) Controller

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, myService, $mdDialog) {

```
GetAllEmployee();
//To Get All Records  
function GetAllEmployee() {
    var result = myService.getEmployees();
    result.then(function (data) {
        $scope.userlist = data.data;
    });
}
GetUserTypeList();
//To Get All Records  
function GetUserTypeList() {
    var result = myService.getUserType();
    result.then(function (data) {
        $scope.usertype = data.data;
    });
}
$scope.clickevent = function(user, item) {
    if (item.opType == 1) {
        edit();
        ListEmp(user);
    } else {
        deleteEmp(user);
    }
}    
function deleteEmp(user) {
    var getData = myService.DeleteEmp(user.Usr_Id);
    getData.then(function(msg) {
      alert('Employee Deleted');
        GetAllEmployee();
    }, function() {
        alert('Error in Deleting bbb');
    });
}  
function ListEmp(user) {
    var resultset = myService.getEmp(user.Usr_Id);
    resultset.then(function(data) {
        alert(data.Usr_UserFName);
        $scope.add_user.UserId = data.Usr_UserId;
        $scope.add_user.FirstName = data.Usr_UserFName;
        $scope.add_user.LastName = data.Usr_UserLName;
        $scope.add_user.phone = data.Usr_PhoneNum;
        $scope.add_user.UserType = data.Usr_Type;
        $scope.add_user.Password = data.Usr_Passowrd;
    });
}
$scope.AddUser = function (add_user) {
    var getData = myService.AddEmp(add_user.Usr_UserId, add_user.Usr_Passowrd, add_user.Usr_UserFName, add_user.Usr_UserLName, add_user.Usr_Type, add_user.Usr_PhoneNum);
    window.location.href = '/Home/UserList';
    GetAllEmployee();       
}})
.controller('WidthDemoCtrl', function ($mdDialog) {
var vm = this;

this.announceClick = function (index) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/Home/About',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: $event,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
    })
};})
```

2) Service.js

```
app.service("myService", function($http) {
  //get All Users
  this.getEmployees = function() {
    return $http.get("/Home/GetAllUsers");
  };
  this.getEmp = function(employeeId) {
    var response = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: "/Home/GetUserById",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        Userid: employeeId
      })
    });
    return response;
  }
  this.DeleteEmp = function(employeeId) {
    var response = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: "/Home/DeleteUser",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        User: employeeId
      })
    });
    return response;
  }
  this.AddEmp = function(userid, password, fname, lname, type, phone) {
    var response = $http({
      method: "post",
      url: "/Home/AddNewUser",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        UserId: userid,
        UserPassword: password,
        UserFName: fname,
        UserLName: lname,
        UserType: type,
        UserPhoneNumber: phone
      })
    });
    return response;
  }
  this.getUserType = function() {
    return $http.get("/Home/GetUserType");
  };
})
```

3) CSHTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak class="md-inline-form">
   <md-content layout-padding>
      <div>
         <form name="userForm">
            <div layout-gt-xs="row">
            </div>
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>User Id</label>
                  <input ng-model="add_user.UserId"  ng-required="true">
               </md-input-container>
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input ng-model="add_user.Password" type="password" ng-required="true">
               </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>First Name</label>
                  <input ng-model="add_user.FirstName"  ng-required="true">
               </md-input-container>
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>Last Name</label>
                  <input ng-model="add_user.LastName"  ng-required="true">
               </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>Phone</label>
                  <input ng-model="add_user.phone"  ng-required="true">
               </md-input-container>
               <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                  <label>User Type</label>
                  <md-select ng-model="add_user.UserType"  ng-required="true">
                     <md-option ng-repeat="type in usertype" value="{{type.Ut_int}}">
                        {{type.Ut_Name}}
                     </md-option>
                  </md-select>
               </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div>
               <md-button ng-click="AddUser(add_user)" type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </md-content>
</div>
<pq-grid options=""></pq-grid>
```

Comment: add_user is my ng-model in cshtml. Alos, i checked in broser i m getting json data but i can't able to use it. something missing.

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to alert with the data..could you put that into the code, and comment where you are erroring?

Comment: Yes, as Brian said, would be better if you put the alert() call which is failing. There are chances that you're using it outside of the "then()" or even after, which will not work

Comment: I updated my code with alert int.but im getting undefined in alert.

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: I find lot of discrepancies in the code. `this.getEmployees()` method is not invoked at all. If you are not invoking this, how do you get the employees  list? Why are you invoking `GetAllEmployee()` method inside `deleteEmp()` method and that too twice? Maybe a plnkr project will give us a clear picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its put my full controller code here. There is another problem i cant able to bind my $mddialog textbox even i pass just normal string data.

Answer (score 0):

Check your json attributes returns from service with following attributes
Usr_UserId
Usr_UserFName
Usr_UserLName
Usr_PhoneNum
Usr_Type
Usr_Passowrd

Comment: i check in browser json returning everything correct.

Comment: Problem is that my $mddialog is not populating with all the elements when i click edit.